# Laravel form open with multiple parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to pass variables with form open with following code:

```
{{ Form::open(['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['note.update','project','1','1']]) }}
```

Here is my NoteController.php file

```
Class NoteController extends BaseController{
    public function update($belongs_to,$unique_id=0,$note_id=0){
        return $unique_id;
    }
}
```

routes.php file is

```
Route::resource('note', 'NoteController');
```

Why I am only able to access $belongs_to variable and $unique_id and $note_Id are always 0 as given as default value??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the routes registered with `Route::resource` only take one url parameter.

Take a look a [this](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

So what you need to do is use this route:

```
Route::patch('note/{belongs_to}/{unique_id?}/{note_id?}', 'NoteController@update');
```

If you want to keep the other routes from `Route::resource` just add it before `Route::resource`

```
Route::patch('note/{belongs_to}/{unique_id?}/{note_id?}', 'NoteController@update');
Route::resource('note', 'NoteController');
```

*If you don't want to add the route like this, you'll have to use query parameters to pass additional information*